# converting rows into columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wonder if anyone can help: I want to convert rows into columns. This is the original table:

I have tried using pivot but this case it is too complex for me.

```
declare @Table AS TABLE
(
TYPE VARCHAR(100) ,
SERIE VARCHAR(100) ,
CUR1 INT,
CUR2 INT
)

INSERT @Table
( TYPE, SERIE, CUR1, CUR2)
VALUES
( 'CORP', 'S1' ,2122,322 ),
( 'CORP', 'S2' ,321,546 ),
( 'SER', 'S1',543,788 ),
( 'SER', 'S2' ,655, 988 )
```

I expect the output to be like the attached table:
[image]

Comment: please show your query

Comment: please post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, a variant of this will help:-

```
    ;with cte as (
    select SERIE, [CORP] as [CORP_CUR1], [SER] as [SER_CUR1] from (
    select type , serie, cur1 from @Table)
    as d
    pivot
    ( max(cur1) for [type] in ( [CORP], [SER]) ) as p
    ),
    ct as (
    select SERIE, [CORP] as [CORP_CUR2], [SER] as [SER_CUR2]  from (
    select type , serie, cur2 from @Table)
    as d
    pivot
    ( max(cur2) for [type] in ( [CORP], [SER]) ) as p
    )
    select cte.SERIE, cte.[CORP_CUR1], cte.[SER_CUR1], ct.[CORP_CUR2], ct.[SER_CUR2] from cte inner join ct on cte.SERIE=ct.SERIE
```